# Вычислить s = 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! + 6!

Tags: vba, for

помогите пожалуйста решить задачу, используя оператор цикла FOR (я новичок, почти толком не разбираюсь, можете написать как можно простым кодом): s = 1! + 2! + ... + 6!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это задача в которой не надо считать факториал для каждого числа

1. вводите переменную, в которую будете накапливать сумму и присваиваете ее `0`
2. вводите переменную, в которую будете накапливать факториал и присваиваете его `1`
3. проходите в цикле от `1` до `6`
4. вычисляете факториал для текущего числа умножением текущего числа на факториал предыдущего числа
5. увеличиваете сумму на значение вычисленного факториала

т.е. ваш алгоритм такой:

```
итог = 0
факториал = 1

цикл от 1 до 6
    факториал = факториал * значение цикла
    итог = итог + факториал

вывод результата
```